# Seeking advise to de-duplicate Month/Week/Day Open when occuring on same day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When a new Month/Week/(Trading)Day starts they often share the same date/time (especially a new week Open always also is a new day Open).

As I want to plot lines for the "Open" of the corresponding timeframe, I am frequently getting duplicates that need quite some logic to eliminate duplicates.

As an example, when a new months starts that also is the start of a new week as well as a new day, I only want to show the monthly open for that occurence - but do not want to show the same occurence as week/day open.

It seems to become close to impossible to handle (in my brain at least) taking 24/7 (crypto), indecies, and Forex sessions with different tradingdays (e.g. pre-market) into consideration. Simply put: I am completely stuck but kinda confident I overcomplicate things/missed some existing functions handling that already or simply misunderstood parts of pine-script concepts.

**Is anyone aware of a library/function/method handling this or got a starter to help me unwiring my mind on this topic?**


Please: I don't expect anyone writing code for me (but happily take an example) but seek a pointer helping me to unwire my brain on how to achieve this in a elegant (and resource friendly) way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to define the three different opens and then use an if / else if statement to only plot the line you want

```
var line dayOpenLine = na
var line weekOpenLine = na
var line monthOpenLine = na

dayChange = ta.change(time('D'))
weekChange = ta.change(time('W'))
monthChange = ta.change(time('M'))
allThree =  dayChange and weekChange and monthChange

if allThree
    monthOpenLine := line.new(bar_index, open, bar_index + 1, open, extend = extend.right)
    line.delete(monthOpenLine[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I actually just got a reply on another thread with a pretty elegant solution using a Switch. I gonna post that as (Accepted) answer in a second, simply since its uber elegant and reducing complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Received from @bjorgum through TV chat.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

switch 
    timeframe.change("M") => line.new(time, open, time_close("M"), open, xloc.bar_time, color = color.red)
    timeframe.change("W") => line.new(time, open, time_close("W"), open, xloc.bar_time, color = color.yellow)
    timeframe.change("D") => line.new(time, open, time_close("D"), open, xloc.bar_time, color = color.green)
```